# How to implement vertical tables using html5/CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

So basically table data are in each row and they are formed horizontal. Like this:

[Normal Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzV9P.jpg)

But I want to put my data in columns so that I could form a vertical table. Like this:

[Vertical Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMS4s.jpg)

Any idea how to approach this? I'm also using bootstrap.

Comment: Can you give more information on how your table is being built? Are you creating this table dynamically or is it hard coded?

Comment: Just make the first columns contain the headings? What is the specific question?

Comment: @lukehillonline No it is not created dynamically. Just a simple table

Comment: @PeeHaa Well yes, but I want to do it semantically. I could do this with css and put my headings in the first td tags of each row. But that does't make any sense so I was wondering if there is any other way to do this

Comment: What td tags? They are headings. Use `th` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the headings in the same row as the data.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><strong>Name</strong></th>
    <td>Name1</td>      
    <td>Name2</td>      
    <td>Name3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><strong>Tell</strong></th>
    <td>Tell1</td>      
    <td>Tell2</td>
    <td>Tell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><strong>Job</strong></th>
    <td>Job1</td>       
    <td>Job2</td>       
    <td>Job3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><strong>Address</strong></th>
    <td>Address1</td>       
    <td>Address2</td>       
    <td>Address3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```